# How do I vertical align with Bootstrap 4.5?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Here is the code that I have.

```
<body style="height: 100vh; margin: 0;
    padding: 0;  ">

<!-- Form Area
============================================= -->
<p>[wpshortcode1]</p>
    <div class="container h-100 ">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <form class="col-sm-6" method="POST" action="../categories/">
                <div class="form-group mb-3">
                    <label for="city" class="form-label">City</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control rounded" id="city" name="destinationCity" placeholder="City">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group mb-3 ">
                    <label for="state" class="control-label">State</label>
                    <div>
                        <select class="form-control" id="state" name="destinationState" placeholder="Please Choose">
                            <option value="">Please Choose</option>
                            <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
                            <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
                            <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
                            <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
                            <option value="CA">California</option>
                            <option value="CO">Colorado</option>
                            <option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
                            <option value="DC">District of Columbia</option>
                            <option value="DE">Delaware</option>
                            <option value="FL">Florida</option>
                            <option value="GA">Georgia</option>
                            <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
                            <option value="IA">Iowa</option>
                            <option value="ID">Idaho</option>
                            <option value="IL">Illinois</option>
                            <option value="IN">Indiana</option>
                            <option value="KS">Kansas</option>
                            <option value="KY">Kentucky</option>
                            <option value="LA">Louisiana</option>
                            <option value="MA">Massachusetts</option>
                            <option value="MD">Maryland</option>
                            <option value="ME">Maine</option>
                            <option value="MI">Michigan</option>
                            <option value="MN">Minnesota</option>
                            <option value="MO">Missouri</option>
                            <option value="MS">Mississippi</option>
                            <option value="MT">Montana</option>
                            <option value="NC">North Carolina</option>
                            <option value="ND">North Dakota</option>
                            <option value="NE">Nebraska</option>
                            <option value="NH">New Hampshire</option>
                            <option value="NJ">New Jersey</option>
                            <option value="NM">New Mexico</option>
                            <option value="NV">Nevada</option>
                            <option value="NY">New York</option>
                            <option value="OH">Ohio</option>
                            <option value="OK">Oklahoma</option>
                            <option value="OR">Oregon</option>
                            <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
                            <option value="PR">Puerto Rico</option>
                            <option value="RI">Rhode Island</option>
                            <option value="SC">South Carolina</option>
                            <option value="SD">South Dakota</option>
                            <option value="TN">Tennessee</option>
                            <option value="TX">Texas</option>
                            <option value="UT">Utah</option>
                            <option value="VA">Virginia</option>
                            <option value="VT">Vermont</option>
                            <option value="WA">Washington</option>
                            <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
                            <option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
                            <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group mb-3">
                    <label for="postalcode">Zip Code</label>
                    <input type="text" name="destinationPostalCode" class="form-control rounded" id="postalcode" placeholder="Zip Code">
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Customer_Data" name="submitCustomerData">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-7">
                <div class="mt-5">
                    <label for="response" class="form-label">Response Body:</label>
                    <textarea class="form-control rounded" id="response" rows="3"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<!-- External JavaScripts
============================================= -->

<?php wp_footer(); ?>

</body>

</html>
```

I have tried align-middle as indicated in the Bootstrap documentation on the the container and the child divs. No luck. Since I am not using inline, inline-block, inline-table, and table cell elements, I guessed that align-items-center would work, but no luck with that either.

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/#align-items

Comment: @isherwood I tried that on this:<div class="row justify-content-center d-flex align-items-center">. Am I using it on the wrong line? I just don't get it.

Comment: your code is working fine can you check this link https://jsfiddle.net/Udhaytitus/oh2a7zke/

Answer (score 0):

Add class `align-items-center` to the row where you want to align the cols. Or add it to every parent where you want to align child elements. For `align-items:center;`  the item needs to be flex.